# Apache rewrite rule percent symbol - facebook

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I am having this issue with my apache and rewrite rules.

My orignal url is something like this:

```
urbana.com.uy/core.php?m=amp&nw=MTQ2NA==
```

When I post it in facebook, the URL change (facebook do it) to this:

```
urbana.com.uy/xcore/?m=nw&nw=MTQ2NA%3D%3D
```

So, facebook convert the `=` symbol to `%3D`

Well, from here no problem.

BUT, I have a rewrite rule in my server that rewrite an URL that doesnt start with www to www.blabla
This are the rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

The work but with a problem.
When a user clic in a URL from facebook, with the `%3D` instead of `=`, my apache change that for a `%25`, like this

```
www.urbana.com.uy/xcore/?m=nw&nw=MTQ2NA%253D%253D
```

and this doesnt work

How can I tell my apache to not change the `%` symbol to `%25` and redirect all the non www no www?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the only reliable answer to your problem is to not send non-url safe values to as the value of a URL query. I would suggest using some form of url encode on your parameter before you send it to facebook, and then a url decode on the other side. In PHP you would generate these like so:

```
<?php
   $parameter_value = url_encode('MTQ2NA==');
   $facebook_url = "http://urbana.com.uy/core.php?m=amp&nw=" . $parameter_value;
?>
```

Then on your server, when you read the value, just perform a URL decode

```
<?php
   $parameter_value = url_decode($_GET['nw']);
?>
```

Other languages will have similar tools to perform this. I realize its not exactly what you're asking for, but the "=" sign is not a url safe character, and sending it in a parameter is going to cause issues even if you can get the rewriting working.